# Java.lang.RuntimeException:setParameters failed at android.hardware.camera.native_setParameter(Native Method)

Tags: java, android, camera

I'm using the Android APIDemo sample code.
 but my phone is G2  Android OS 2.1

Answer (score 2):

before you set caemra Parameters , you can use camera.getParameters().flatten()  to log all the parameters that camera support. so you can use the right parameter.

Answer (score 1):

replace surfaceCreated methood to  this , and tell me if it work

```
 public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder){
        // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the
        // preview.


        Log.d(TAG, "surfaceCreated camera id" + mCamera);

        try {
            CamcorderProfile profile ;

            int numCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
            if (numCameras > 1) {
            profile = (CamcorderProfile
                        .get(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT,CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
            }
            else{

                profile = (CamcorderProfile
                        .get(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK,CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
            }


            Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
            parameters.setPreviewSize(profile.videoFrameWidth, profile.videoFrameHeight);
            mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }}
```